# Memory efficient way to use Redis pubsub on per user basis in go service?

Tags: go, redis, graphql, publish-subscribe, go-redis

We use GraphQL subscriptions that push data to the client. On the GraphQl server, written in golang, we connect to a pubsub channel for each user subscription (channel is unique for each user). While testing we noticed that the go service memory consumption started to grow really fast with every new user subscription.

Any recommendations on how we make this implementation less memory intensive?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do now is to profile your program to find out the reason behind the problem
https://medium.com/@openmohan/profiling-in-golang-3e51c68eb6a8

Follow the article for more information on how to profile a programs